# electrum 2.6.4 Bitcoin wallet on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, backports, bitcoin

I'm running Debian 7 stable and because the old version available on Wheezy can't send out BTC, I'd like to upgrade to a newer version which is available in jessie-backports. Is it possible to use that version? If so, how to modify sources.list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Electrum is written in Python, and the dependencies of the version in Jessie backports are compatible with the version of Python available in Wheezy, it should be possible to do what you're suggesting. As `root`,

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports electrum
```

This will pull in `electrum` and `python-electrum` from Jessie backports, but won't affect the rest of your packages. Some of the suggested dependencies (*e.g.* `python-btchip`) aren't available even in Jessie backports, so some features may be missing.

Comment: Can you please give a proposal for Debian Stretch?

Comment: @Léo Stretch has [`electrum` 2.7.9](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/electrum) in its repositories, no need for anything fancy.

Comment: Do you have any other recommendation besides `electrum` for having bitcoins in Debian?

Comment: @Léo no, I don’t. (I don’t use Electrum either.)